# How to convert theano symbolic vector of interger labels to binarized symbolic matrix label?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, theano

I am a newbie in Theano and trying to convert labels of theano vector to theano matrix. One of the NN application required labels in the form of a binary matrix of MxN where M is the number of samples and N is the number of class. e.g., labels=[0,1,2,1,2,3], the banary_labels should be 
[[1,0,0,0]; [0,1,0,0]; [0,0,1,0]; [0,1,0,0]; [0,0,1,0]; [0,0,0,1]]

*I have written the following code but unable to figure it what is the problem*

```
def encode_labels(y,batch_size,max_label):
  y=T.ivector('y')
  b_y=T.zeros(shape=(batch_size,max_label+1),dtype=theano.config.floatX)
  enc,update=theano.scan(lambda i,j:1,
    sequences=[T.arange(batch_size),y],
    outputs_info=b_y)

  encode_l=theano.function(inputs=y,outputs=enc)
  return encode_l

y=[0,1,2,1,2,3]
b_y=encode_labels(y,6,3)
print b_y
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called one-hot encoding. Have a look at Keras implementation (to_categorical) [here.](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/np_utils.py)